# CreateGraphics not available in iTextSharp PdfTemplate?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I'm working on a conversion project from Java to .Net and it also involves converting pdf reports from itext to iTextSharp.
I cannot find `CreateGraphics` method in iTextSharp. I've read it is deprecated in java, not sure whether it was there in iTextSharp or no.

`PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
PdfTemplate tp = cb.CreateTemplate(760f, 400f);
Graphics2D g2d = tp.CreateGraphics(760f, 400f, new DefaultFontMapper());`

`Graphics2D` is java.awt.Graphics2D class which I'm getting from .dlls converted from .jar files.

Any alternatives to `CreateGraphics` will also do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `PdfGraphics2D` class in the Java version of iText, is an implementation of the abstract `java.awt.Graphics2D` class in the Java SDK. Since there is no `Graphics2D` class in C#, there is no `PdfGraphics2D` class in iTextSharp.

Why would you need such a class in C#? The `PdfGraphics2D` class was provided for Java developers who don't want to learn PDF syntax. Instead they could use Java syntax.

Since you are a C# developer, it doesn't really make sense to provide a C# class that allows you to use Java syntax. Instead, you should use PDF syntax, such as `LineTo()`, `MoveTo()`, and `Stroke()` to draw lines, `Rectangle()` and `Stroke()` to draw a rectangle, and so on.

All of these methods are available in a class called `PdfContentByte`. The methods that can be used are explained in ISO-32000-1.

Comment: I am trying to find a quick way to convert from java to c#.  The g2d object further will be used by `JFreeChart` object to generate the chart. So was thinking not to tweak much and get a solution. I've also converted the Jfree chart dll which I'm currenlty using

Comment: There is no quick way to do that.